# How can I develop using a local VM server without using URLs with ports in them?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm setting up a linux server in a VM for my development.

Previously I've had PHP, MySQL etc etc all installed locally on my Mac. Apart from being a security risk, it's a drag to maintain and keep up to date, and there's a risk that an OS upgrade will wipe part of your setup out as the changes you make are fairly non-standard.

Having the entire server contained within a VM makes it easily upgradable and portable between machines. It means I can have the same configuration as the destination server and with shared folders even if the VM gets corrupted my work is safe on the host machine.

Previously with the local installation I was able to develop on convenient URLs like http://site.dev. I'd quite like to carry this over to the VM way of development but I'm struggling to figure out how, if it's possible at all.

Here's the problem:

- In Bridged mode, the VM is part of the same network as the host. This is great but I can't choose a fixed IP address as I may be joining other networks and that address may be taken already. I'd like a consistent way of addressing my VM.
- In NAT mode I can't directly address the VM without using port forwarding. I can use http://site.dev if I use the hosts file to forward that to localhost and then localhost:8080 forwards to the vm:80. The trouble is I have to access http://site.dev:8080 which is inconvenient for URL construction.

Does anyone know a way around this? I'm using ubuntu server and virtualbox.

Thanks!

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to define a separate host-only network adapter and use that for host->guest communication.

You can do this by powering down the guest and adding the adapter in the VM settings. Once that's done you can boot the guest again and configure the new network interface however suits you best. I chose a fixed IP address in an unused range.